# What is Big O of two loops

Tags: java, performance, time, big-o

I am trying to find the Big-O for the Summing function. I know the two loops usually mean that N^2 run time but this is just one N but j is running many more than N itself.

```java
int Summing( int n )
{
    int i 
    int j
    int s = 0;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(j=0; j < i; j++) {
            s += i*i;
          }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you know that you can empirically determine the complexity simply by adding a counter in the code and running it, then plotting the result? If you have a hunch for what the complexity is, this is a helpful way to confirm it.

Comment: It's O(j*n) and since j is a constant, you can drop j.  So, the result is O(n).

Comment: @ChengThao **j** - isn't a constant

Comment: This code has **quadratic** time complexity. Declaration of variables **i** and **j** outside of the loop is unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko You are right.  I wasn't paying attention enough to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the exact time the inner loop takes as a function of i and then sum it up over all values that i takes.

Here the number of times the innermost section is run is `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1) = (n-1)*n/2 = (n^2)/2 - n/2` which is `O(n^2)`